# How to use filtering option in R?

Tags: r, filter

```
ind_betas <- ind_betas %>%
+     filter(!is.na(Index)) %>%
+     droplevels()
```

> Error in ind_betas %>% filter(!is.na(Index)) %>% droplevels() :
> could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Please improve your question explaining your problem and your intended goal, not just posting code. For what concerns `%>%`, you have to include `library(magrittr)`.

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

As Matteo points out, this error is caused because the `%>%` notation comes from the `magittr` package which it seems you have not loaded.

You likely want to run:

```
library(tidyverse)

ind_betas <- ind_betas %>%
     filter(!is.na(Index)) %>%
     droplevels()
```

Which should work. Note `tidyverse` includes a number of additional packages which are useful for data cleaning/analysis.